# ES6 code not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a es6 js file that is used as a library. The js file depends on jquery as you see. I am using Webpack.

In the JS file, I have the line below which results in _interopRequireWildcard in the eventual es5 code that I copied below. Since jquery is not esModule, after evaluating the condition `obj && obj.__esModule`, the jQuery function get copied to a Object. I am also using this code with typescript. It works with Typescript but is failing with es6.

**ES6 code snippet**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

let setupObject = function setupObject(element) {
 let aButton = $(dropdownButtonSelector); //Fail's here with error
                  //Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
}
exports default setupObject;
```

**Transpiled ES5 code**

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
 value: true
});

var _jquery = __webpack_require__(1);

var $ = _interopRequireWildcard(_jquery);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) {
  if (obj && obj.__esModule) { //obj.__esModule = undefined for jquery
    return obj;
} else {
    var newObj = {};
    if (obj != null ) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
                newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    newObj.default = obj;
    return newObj;
  }
}

var setupObject = function setupObject(element) {
 var aButton = $(dropdownButtonSelector); //Fail's here with error
                  //Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
}
exports.default = setupObject;
```

Comment: Try `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: It only targets the default export, which is transpiled to commonJS as `module.exports` (assuming your jQuery version has hooks for commonJS). Does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your import takes all available imports and wraps them in an object:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

So `$` would probably look something like this:

```
{Animation: function Animation(...),Callback: function (...), Deferred: function(...), default: function(selector, context){}, fn: Object[0], .... }
```

Thus your `TypeError`:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

(See: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#more_on_importing_and_exporting)

Try using the following statement instead, it will only import the `default` export:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Since your `jQuery` probably still has CommonJS exports (`module.exports`), its exports will automatically be mapped to `export default` by babel.

Comment: `$` object does not look like `{default: function jQuery()}`. As you see from the else part of the condition in `interopRequireWildcard`. All the object properties are copied to a new empty literal object which is then returned.

Comment: What does it look like though? The else part only specifies that it is a new object with all the properties of `obj`.

Comment: Looks like this: `{Animation: function Animation(...),Callback: function (...), Deferred: function(...), default:  function(selector, context){}, fn: Object[0], .... }`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback in the form of a downvote. If you could elaborate on the reason, maybe I could even learn something from it.

Comment: Well, This worked with es6 but failed with typescript. It worked with both when I used `var $=require('jquery')`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Your original question did not include typescript though… you added that later on.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the same file working with both es6 and typescript. I actually changed the code to use `require('jquery')` instead of `import $ from 'jquery'`. So here is the final code

**Final ES6 code snippet**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
let setupObject = function setupObject(element) {
  let aButton = $(dropdownButtonSelector); //Fail's here with error
              //Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
}
exports default setupObject;
```

**Transpiled ES5 code with Webpack that uses this as es6**

```
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var setupObject = function setupObject(element) {
  var $ = __webpack_require__(1);
  var aButton = $(dropdownButtonSelector); 
  ...
};

exports.default = setupDropdown;
```

**Transpiled ES5 code with Webpack that uses this as typescript**

```
 !(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__, exports], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function (require, exports) {
"use strict";
   var setupObject = function setupObject(element) {
      var $ = __webpack_require__(10);
      var aButton = $(dropdownButtonSelector);
      ...
   }
   Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
   exports.default = setupDropdown;
 }.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__), __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));
```